# Iterate through enums in C?

Tags: c, enums

let's say I have a couple of hardware registers which are defined within an enum:

```
typedef enum registers
{
    REG1 = 0,
    REG2 = 1,
    REG3 = 2,
    REG4 = 4,
    REG5 = 6,
    REG6 = 8,
    
    REG_MAX,
    
}
```

I have default values for these registers(actually not decided in which way to define them, #define, array or enum...):

```
// This is just conceptual, not really an enum, array or #define :)
typedef enum values
{
    VALUE_REG1 = A,
    VALUE_REG2 = B,
    VALUE_REG3 = C,
    VALUE_REG4 = 53,
    VALUE_REG5 = 88,
    VALUE_REG6 = 24,
    
    MAX_NUM_REG_VALUES    
}
```

I have a function which can read the hardware registers:

```
uint8 readRegs(uint8 regaddr);
```

Now I would like to loop through `registers`, and on each element call the `readRegs()` function and compare it to the enum `regvalues`. It looks like:

```
registers regs;
reg_values values;
uint8 readfromregs;

for (regs = REG1; regs <= REG_MAX; regs++)
{
    readfromregs = readRegs(regs);
    for (values = VALUE_REG1; reg_values <= MAX_NUM_REG_VALUES; reg_values++)
    {
        if (readfromregs != values)
        {
             // Value not correct
        }
        else
        {
             // value correct
        }
    }
}
```

This will not work because it's not possible to iterate in enum in this way. Does anybody have a better solution? How to define the construct `enum reg_values`?
The *enum registers* must be fix (this can not be changes to array).

Comment: `MAX_NUM_REG_VALUES` is 25, just so you know.

Comment: An array, of course. You could define array of pairs or structs (e.g., pair<register, default_value>).

Comment: @KonstantinL That looks a lot like C++, not C.  But yes, an array of some non-C++ datatype.

Comment: Sorry. Well, then use just an array of struct: struct CRegister { int register; int defaultValue; } registerArray[100];

Comment: The `REG_MAX` trick should only be used when the enum numbers are adjacent, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Same with `MAX_NUM_REG_VALUES`. Remove those constants, they are misleading.

Comment: @Lundin It would not be misleading with `MAX_NUM_REG_VALUES`, it would be *wrong*. `MAX_NUM_REG_VALUES` would be 25.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably define a struct

```
struct RegInfo
{
    registers number;
    values defaultValue;
}
```

Then I would create an array matching the register number to the default value

```
struct RegInfo registerInfo[] =
{
    { REG1, VALUE_REG1 },
    { REG2, VALUE_REG2 },
    { REG3, VALUE_REG3 },
    { REG4, VALUE_REG4 },
    { REG5, VALUE_REG5 },
    { REG6, VALUE_REG6 },
};
```

Now to iterate the registers:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof registerInfo / sizeof(RegInfo) ; ++i)
{
    values value = readFromReg( registerInfo[i].number);
    if (value != registerInfo[i].defaultValue)
    {
         // Not the default
    }
}
```

If you want an inner loop foe each value, same trick except the array can be directly of the values

```
values allValues[] = { VALUE_REG1, Value_REG2, ... , VALUE_REG6 };
```

There is a risk that you'll forget to put new values/registers in the relevant array, but that's what unit testing is for.

Comment: If you worry about messing up the array initialization during maintenance, you can do `struct RegInfo registerInfo[] = { [0] = { REG1, VALUE_REG1 }, [1] =  { REG2, VALUE_REG2 }, ... }`. If anyone would come and alter that list later on, it will be hard for them to mess up.

Comment: Also, an optimization nit-pick is that structs like these give worse cache performance than keeping one separate array of enums and one with values. I'd say that readability of the code is more important, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Lundin I was thinking more in terms of if somebody added a new enum value and forgot to add it to the array.

Comment: I posted a complementing answer regarding how to fix that issue.

Answer (score 2):

`REG_MAX` will be `9` and `MAX_NUM_REG_VALUES` will be `25` so you can't use those. You'll have to enumerate the constants in a different way.

Based on the struct solution in another answer by @JeremyP, you could use a 3rd enum for the actual indices:

```
typedef enum
{
  REG_INDEX1 = REG1,
  REG_INDEX2 = REG2,
  REG_INDEX3 = REG3,
  REG_INDEX4 = REG4,
  REG_INDEX5 = REG5,
  REG_INDEX6 = REG6,
  REG_INDEX_N // number of registers
} reg_index;
```

This enables some ways to improve data integrity:

```
struct RegInfo registerInfo[] =
{
  [REG_INDEX1] = { REG1, VALUE_REG1 },
  [REG_INDEX2] = { REG2, VALUE_REG2 },
  [REG_INDEX3] = { REG3, VALUE_REG3 },
  [REG_INDEX4] = { REG4, VALUE_REG4 },
  [REG_INDEX5] = { REG5, VALUE_REG5 },
  [REG_INDEX6] = { REG6, VALUE_REG6 },
};

_Static_assert(sizeof(registerInfo)/sizeof(*registerInfo) == REG_INDEX_N, 
               "Enum not in sync with array initializer");
```

This is the solution I would recommend.

---

If you are very pedantic with data integrity and want to avoid code repetition, there is also some evil macro magic you can use. Namely "X macros" that come at the expense of severely reduced readability:

```
// whatever A, B and C is supposed to be
#define A 10
#define B 11
#define C 12

#define REG_LIST \
  X(0, A)        \
  X(1, B)        \
  X(2, C)        \
  X(4, 53)       \
  X(6, 88)       \
  X(8, 24)       \

int main (void)
{
  // iterate through the value pairs:
  #define X(reg, val) printf("reg: %d val:%.2d\n", reg, val);
  REG_LIST
  #undef X
}
```

Similarly, you can use X macros to create the enums:

```
typedef enum // create REG1, REG2, REG4 etc
{
  #define X(key, val) REG##key = key,
  REG_LIST
  #undef X
} registers;

typedef enum // create VALUE_REG1, VALUE_REG2, VALUE_REG4 etc
{
  #define X(key, val) VALUE_REG##key = val, 
  REG_LIST
  #undef X
} values;
```